# How to add createReducer with old reducer function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I like the new way to create reducer with createReducer but I am not able to find any migration path how you can migrate your old reducer to this new function.

I would like to add new state mutation in createReducer way and combine both reducer then overtime I move things.

any idea how to do?

Answer (score 2):

Read [Mixing Action Styles In NgRx State](https://medium.com/@brandontroberts/mixing-action-styles-in-ngrx-state-562332a2d799) by Brandon Roberts.

```
import { createReducer, on, union } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as LegacyCounterActions from './legacy-counter.actions';
import * as CounterActions from './counter.actions';
export const initialState = 0;
type State = number;
const counterReducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(CounterActions.increment, state => state + 1)
);
const CounterActionsUnion = union({...CounterActions});
type Actions = 
  | LegacyCounterActions.Union
  | typeof CounterActionsUnion;
export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Actions) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LegacyCounterActions.CounterActionTypes.Increment:
      return state + 1;
    default:
      return counterReducer(state, action);
  }
}
```